# ejbcontext via jndi in ejb2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

How can I get `EJBContext` instance in ejb2 stateless bean via jndi?

I tried following:

```
Object o = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
```

but it failed as ejbcontext is not found by that name. However this code worked in ejb3 bean.

Probably I need to add resource reference to bean descriptor, but following also did not work:

```
<resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>java:comp/EJBContext</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.ejb.EJBContext</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: What code attempted to perform the lookup?  EJBContext can only be looked up within an EJB method.  A servlet cannot lookup EJBContext.

Comment: @bkail, I performed lookup in ejb bean's method

Comment: Sorry, I just looked more carefully at your resource-ref: you should remove that.  `java:comp/EJBContext` is built-in, so you should not attempt to declare it as a resource-ref.

Comment: @bkail, I tried with and without `resource-ref` it does not work in both cases

Comment: Can you show the failing stack trace?  Perhaps that will give a hint as to what's going wrong.

Comment: @bkail, I dont have it offhand, but there is nothing interesting. It says that it can not find such jndi name. I have checked jndi view and ejb2 beans actually don't have ejb context in their contexts.

Comment: Perhaps it's simply a product bug.